# Visual Studio tool for managing Entity Framework migrations?

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio

Is there a Visual Studio tool or GUI extension for managing Entity Framework migrations, rather than having to type repetitive commands into the Package Manager console.

I'm looking for something that will save me time, and save me from having to remember all of the commands and their options.

(Example of the commands I'm referring to:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/data/jj591621.aspx)